# XML editing Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm looking for some help please cleaning up XML files, in python.
Below is just a little snippet of code from 50+thousands lines of code.
I have many XML files of the same sort of data.

```
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <SORT_INFO>
    <sort_type>sort order</sort_type>
  </SORT_INFO>
  <ALL_INSTANCES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>0</start>
      <end>17.96</end>
      <code>14. Jordan Brian Henderson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>34.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>7</ID>
      <start>7.96</start>
      <end>8.96</end>
      <code>Start</code>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>8</ID>
      <start>10.28</start>
      <end>30.28</end>
      <code>26. Andrew Robertson</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>61.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>68.0</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1321</ID>
      <start>3770.67</start>
      <end>3790.67</end>
      <code>3. Fabinho</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Liverpool FC</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>62.7</pos_x>
      <pos_y>3.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>1882</ID>
      <start>5695.17</start>
      <end>5715.17</end>
      <code>2. Fabio Cardoso</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Porto</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Interceptions</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>2nd half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>8.1</pos_x>
      <pos_y>46.3</pos_y>
    </instance>
  </ALL_INSTANCES>
  <ROWS>
    <row>
      <code>20. Vitinha</code>
      <sort_order>15</sort_order>
      <R>51400</R>
      <G>51400</G>
      <B>51400</B>
    </row>
    <row>
      <code>11. Pepe</code>
      <sort_order>16</sort_order>
      <R>51400</R>
      <G>51400</G>
      <B>51400</B>
    </row>
  </ROWS>
</file>
"""
```

I'd like to remove everything before `<ALL_INSTANCES>` and everything after `</ALL_INSTANCES>`

I'd also like to remove any of the `instance` tags that include `<code>Start</code>`

Would it be possible to do this for all XML's in a folder?

Thanks

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup for this, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070215/10473393

Answer (score 0):

See below (grab the nodes you need , create a new xml doc and dump it)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
   <SORT_INFO>
      <sort_type>sort order</sort_type>
   </SORT_INFO>
   <ALL_INSTANCES>
      <instance>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <start>0</start>
         <end>17.96</end>
         <code>14. Jordan Brian Henderson</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>1st half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
         <pos_y>34.0</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>7</ID>
         <start>7.96</start>
         <end>8.96</end>
         <code>Start</code>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>8</ID>
         <start>10.28</start>
         <end>30.28</end>
         <code>26. Andrew Robertson</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>1st half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>61.7</pos_x>
         <pos_y>68.0</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>1321</ID>
         <start>3770.67</start>
         <end>3790.67</end>
         <code>3. Fabinho</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>2nd half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>62.7</pos_x>
         <pos_y>3.7</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>1882</ID>
         <start>5695.17</start>
         <end>5715.17</end>
         <code>2. Fabio Cardoso</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Porto</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Interceptions</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>2nd half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>8.1</pos_x>
         <pos_y>46.3</pos_y>
      </instance>
   </ALL_INSTANCES>
   <ROWS>
      <row>
         <code>20. Vitinha</code>
         <sort_order>15</sort_order>
         <R>51400</R>
         <G>51400</G>
         <B>51400</B>
      </row>
      <row>
         <code>11. Pepe</code>
         <sort_order>16</sort_order>
         <R>51400</R>
         <G>51400</G>
         <B>51400</B>
      </row>
   </ROWS>
</file>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
instances = root.find('ALL_INSTANCES')
for instance in instances.findall('instance'):
    if instance.find('code').text == 'Start':
        instances.remove(instance)
file  = ET.Element('file')
file.append(instances)
ET.dump(file)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
   <ALL_INSTANCES>
      <instance>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <start>0</start>
         <end>17.96</end>
         <code>14. Jordan Brian Henderson</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>1st half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
         <pos_y>34.0</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>8</ID>
         <start>10.28</start>
         <end>30.28</end>
         <code>26. Andrew Robertson</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>1st half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>61.7</pos_x>
         <pos_y>68.0</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>1321</ID>
         <start>3770.67</start>
         <end>3790.67</end>
         <code>3. Fabinho</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Liverpool FC</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Passes accurate</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>2nd half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>62.7</pos_x>
         <pos_y>3.7</pos_y>
      </instance>
      <instance>
         <ID>1882</ID>
         <start>5695.17</start>
         <end>5715.17</end>
         <code>2. Fabio Cardoso</code>
         <label>
            <group>Team</group>
            <text>Porto</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Action</group>
            <text>Interceptions</text>
         </label>
         <label>
            <group>Half</group>
            <text>2nd half</text>
         </label>
         <pos_x>8.1</pos_x>
         <pos_y>46.3</pos_y>
      </instance>
   </ALL_INSTANCES>
</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Alternatively, you can have Python run external [XSLT processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

Specifically, below XSLT runs the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy document as is and then re-designs `<file>` (i.e., root) to only return its `<ALL_INSTANCES>` child. A second empty template is run for the conditional XPath logic, `instance[code='Start']`, to remove such nodes from tree. No loops required for this approach!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements = "*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="file">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ALL_INSTANCES"/>
      </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="instance[code='Start']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA2e)</kbd>

**Python**

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Style.xsl")

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
result.write_output("Output.xml")
```